# Setting the ID order in Handsontable

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, handsontable

I have set up an HTML table using Handsontable. I want the ID to be sorted starting from row 2. How can I do it?

```
    window.hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: datas,
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: false,
    dropdownMenu: true,
    contextMenu: true,
    height: 'auto',
    // width: '100%',
    // stretchH: 'last',
    contextMenu: true,

    cells: function (row, col) {
        let cellProperties = {};
        if (row == 0) {
            // Highlight the first row
            cellProperties.className = 'spotlight'
        }
        return cellProperties;
    },

    licenseKey: 'non-commercial-and-evaluation'
});
}
```

[image]

Comment: Not clear. Your screenshot has Sector and Percentage, but you talk about ID. If you want to have the rows sorted simply sort you data ahead of time. If you want to user to sort on any column add options `columnSorting: true, sortIndicator: true,`

Comment: Handontable does not have an option to block a position of a column other than fixedRowsTop but I do not know if that meets your project requirements. Based on your screenshot it looks like you could also benefit from passing that row to nestedHeaders if you already have a column on the top. Alternatively, if you do not like those two options you can also run moveRows() method in the afterColumnSort hook to get the row back on the top.